# How to create a dictionary app in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

What are the options/approaches available in React-Native for developing a mobile dictionary app.

Answer (score 1):

its depend to word count if it is to large i recommend to using a react-native db package like

https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB
or
https://github.com/realm/realm-js